# Data with two delimiters in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a text file that has more than one delimiter. This a sample of the data:

```
12 ->3 4 5
14->2 1
1->3 5 6
```

I wonder if there is a simple way to obtain the data in the following format:

```
12 3
12 4
12 5
14 2
14 1
 1 3
 1 5
 1 6
```

Comment: data.frames do not have delimiters (files have them). It is unclear what the data is that you have. Please provide an example of your data. "12 -> 3 4 5" is not R.

Comment: this a data that i have and i would read it in R in a such a way 12 was repeated as we have more value beside it."12->3 4 5" n, i would that R read it as "12 3 12 4 12 5".

Comment: @Camilla - so I assume this data is in a text file or similar?

Comment: yes is in a text file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was trying to reproduce your situation using `cat` and hope it is what you really have there. So let's say this is your file

```
cat("12 ->3 4 5
     14->2 1
     1->3 5 6", 
    file = "test.txt")
```

Using `data.table`, I'm reading it quickly by specifying some wrong separator so the result will be a single column data set

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("test.txt", 
            sep = ",", 
            header = FALSE)
```

Next step is a double split, first separating the numbers on both sides of the arrow (`->`), and then splitting by group

```
dt[, tstrsplit(V1, "\\s*->\\s*", type.convert = TRUE)
   ][, strsplit(V2, "\\s+"), by = .(indx = V1)]
#    indx V1
# 1:   12  3
# 2:   12  4
# 3:   12  5
# 4:   14  2
# 5:   14  1
# 6:    1  3
# 7:    1  5
# 8:    1  6
```

Answer (score 4):

The textConnection function simulates a read for a file:

```
 txt <- "12 ->3 4 5
 14->2 1
 1->3 5 6"

 inpt <- strsplit(readLines(textConnection(txt)), "\\s*->")
 inpt
#---------
[[1]]
[1] "12"    "3 4 5"

[[2]]
[1] "14"  "2 1"

[[3]]
[1] "1"     "3 5 6"

do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
     lapply(inpt, function(i) {inp <- scan(text=i[2])
                               list( col1= rep(i[1], length(inp) ), col2=inp)} ) )

#  --- can suppress the scan read messages ... see `?scan`
Read 3 items
Read 2 items
Read 3 items
   col1 col2
4    12    3
5    12    4
6    12    5
41   14    2
51   14    1
61    1    3
7     1    5
8     1    6
```